# Optaplannaer: how to delete the planning entity instance that violate the rule in the drl file?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm attempting to obtain "0" hard and "0" soft constraints all the time.
If any of the planning entity instances violates any of the rules listed in the .drl file, I want to remove it from the solution schedule.
i.e. if I have 20 planning entity instances to be scheduled, but they can't be all included in the schedule without any violations but 15 can do so, then I want to remove the other 5 planning entity instances from the obtained schedule. In this case I will obtain a schedule contains only 15 planning entity instances with "0" hard and "0" soft constraints violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **Overconstrained planning** in docs and hospital bed planning examples.

This question is asked frequently here on stackoverflow (hence the short answer). [Last time was last week even :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123604/optaplanner-algorithm-impact-on-hard-constraints)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your quick response, really I appreciate this.